# Export multiple tables among servers

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We currently have an SSIS package that exports about 70 large tables nightly, with truncate and load at the destination. Our tables keep changing, we sometimes add some tables and remove some and editing the SSIS package accordingly is tiring.

Is there a way to have a text file or a table with the list of table names in it and have an SSIS package to loop the table and perform the export? That way, it is easier to handle dynamic list of tables that get exported.

Any links, pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered bcp/`BULK INSERT` instead?  It's easily scriptable, as long as you don't need much transformation.

Comment: Are the tables that you are adding/removing always coming from the same set of tables? Or are you creating brand new tables? For how long do you anticipate you will have to be making these kinds of changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are looking for is to dynamically create tables in the destination.
or in other words Copying tables from Source to destination programmatically

here is a very useful article that transfers tables from access to sql dynamically
but you can take the same concept and apply it on your source as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298806/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-list-of-ms-access-tables-within-an-ssis-packag